# Rubydo doesn't execute currently selected in VIM

Tags: ruby, vim

If I have a line selected in vim for example:

```
puts 'Hello world'
```

and highlight this line, then type :rubydo the line doesn't execute, instead I get an error that "E471: Argument required" The same error also happens for the command :ruby % which I have been lead to believe should execute the current file. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

None of those commands do what you expect. The documentation is helpful here:

```
:help :ruby
:help :rubydo
```

To execute the current line, yank it with `yy` and do:

```
:ruby <C-r>"<CR>
```

To run the current script, write it with `:w` then do:

```
:!ruby %<CR>
```

Comment: If it's multiple lines it seems to throw an error saying: "SyntaxError: eval:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input" Is there a good way to run multiple lines?

Comment: Why don't you simply use Pry or some other Ruby REPL?

Comment: Because it would be easier for a ruby presentation I'm doing to be able to execute lines in VIM rather than going back and forth between vim and a REPL.